# Keep getting "Run-time error '1004': Select method of Worksheet class failed when trying to select a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

What I really need is a way to select multiple worksheets in a workbook based on index and/or location in the tab lineup. However, even the simplest select-by-index code is returning this frustrating error.

Here's the simplest code that still returns the error:

```
Sub testselect()
Worksheets(1).Select
End Sub
```

And here's the gist of what I'd like to make work, but probably won't even after I solve this frustrating error:

```
Sub testselect2()
Worksheets(Array(Worksheets(1), Worksheets(2), Worksheets(3), Worksheets(4))).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro and comparing the generated code with what you have?

Comment: Make sure the worksheet is not *Hidden* or protected from being **Select**ed

Comment: `Worksheets(Array(1, 2, 3, 4)).Select`?

Answer (score 0):

You're entering the Array wrong:

```
Sub testselect2()
Sheets(Array(1, 2, 3, 4)).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: That's what I tried at first but got another weird error. Remember: I'm getting the error when I try to select just one sheet, so I can't hope to select the array until I solve that.

Comment: Do you have the first worksheet hidden? If you try and select a worksheet that is hidden or very hidden it will return that error. Try selecting them by name to test.